# Why does my accept header keep getting changed from application/json to */*

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, cross-domain

I'm trying to send an ajax request to a WebAPI service with the accept header of 'application/json'

when I set a break point in the service, I see that the accept header is coming through as "*/*". This doesn't work out for me because our code checks for our "known" media types and rejects the request if not found.

Here is the ajax request in it's current state:

```
$.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        accept: {
            json: 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            displayUsers(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        }
    });
```

I've tried it in IE, Chrome, and Firefox. All the same. I am using cors.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `dataType: json` in the ajax request?

Comment: i did try that. same result

Answer (score 0):

Does your response (or the OPTIONS response, in case of pre-flighted CORS) contain `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept` allowing the accept header when you make the cross-domain request? My guess is that you don't and the browsers switch to the default behavior of sending `*/*`.

Comment: It does. But at the same time, I was under the impression that the restriction was only enforced if the header was present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still no clear on what the real issue was, but I was able to get through it by setting the headers collection rather than just the accept header like one would normally do:

```
$.ajax({
        url: requestUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
         'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            displayUsers(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, exception) {
            alert(exception);
        }
    });
```